# Python - psycopg - duplicate inserts

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to insert in a Postgres database several entities. First a building and then the (several ?) building stairs.

Here is a minimal viable example :

```py
import psycopg

def get_conn():
    database = 'XXXX'
    username = 'XXXX'
    hostname = '127.0.0.1'
    return psycopg.connect("dbname='%s' user='%s' host='%s'"%(database, username, hostname))

def prepare_bdd():
    conn = get_conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(""" drop table if exists test_building_name """)
    cur.execute(""" drop table if exists test_building_stairs """)
    cur.execute(""" create table test_building_name (builing_name varchar) """)
    cur.execute(""" create table test_building_stairs (name varchar, level int) """)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

class Building:
    def __init__(self, building_name=None, stairs_list=[]):
        self.building_name = building_name
        self.stairs_list = stairs_list

    def save(self):
        conn = get_conn()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # save the Building entity
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test_building_name(builing_name) VALUES('%s')"""%self.building_name)
        # foreach stair, save it too
        for stair in self.stairs_list:
            stair.save()
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

class BuildingStairs:
    def __init__(self, building_name=None, floor_level=None):
        self.building_name = building_name
        self.floor_level = floor_level

    def save(self):
        conn = get_conn()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # save the BuildingStairs entity
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test_building_stairs(name, level) VALUES('%s', %i)"""%(self.building_name, self.floor_level))

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Empty & recreate tables
    prepare_bdd()

    # create test lines
    building1 = Building(building_name="A")
    building1.stairs_list.append(BuildingStairs(building_name="A", floor_level=0))
    building1.save()

    building2 = Building(building_name="B")
    building2.stairs_list.append(BuildingStairs(building_name="B", floor_level=1))
    building2.stairs_list.append(BuildingStairs(building_name="B", floor_level=2))
    building2.save()

    building3 = Building(building_name="C")
    building3.stairs_list.append(BuildingStairs(building_name="C", floor_level=3))
    building3.save()
```

problem : all right for the Building entities but the BuildingStairs are duplicated. Do you see where it comes from ?

| builing_name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

| name | level |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

It should be

| name | level |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

Comment: If it can help...
I think it inserts "A" then "A & B" then "A & B & C"

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am not sure what you mean... I don't see how it relates to my code ?

Comment: You are using a mutable default argument too: `...stairs_list=[]):`

Comment: Indeed it works if I remove the default value in the __init__() functions.

Thanks a lot